# How to inject something to stdin of another process

Tags: shell, redirect, command-line, stdin, file-descriptor

Is it possible to start an interactive shell program and inject something to its stdin, keep it running afterwards, and that in a single line?

I'd like to start electron -i (REPL mode)  and execute *.load index.js* right away. It has no switch that accepts code to execute unlike many other REPLs.

```
echo ".load index.js" | electron -i
```

will execute but terminate immediately.

Could juggling with filedescriptors somehow achieve this?

**Interesting resources**

- https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html
- https://blog.protocolsyntax.com/2016/10/18/linuxunix-pipes-file-descriptors-and-process-substitution/

Comment: It'd be more practical if `electron` had an option for running commands at start; like vim's `-c` option. Check if it has one, and make a feature request to `electron` developers if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with `expect`, like this:

```
expect -c 'spawn electron -i; send .load index.js\r; interact'
```